# Magento 2 REST API Order Management

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am using Magento 2 and want to manage orders using **REST API** from a third party portal. I am facing two problems:

1. Paypal orders when placed go to status of Complete instead of
   Processing and then i am unable to ship the order and add tracking
   details. Shipping via API says that a Complete order cant not be
   shipped.
2. All card payments have a status of Processing and once a card
   payment order is shipped without tracking details i am unable to add
   tracking details to the order.

can someone please help with above.

thanks